# Thin start ssl is throwing invalid parse error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ssl, ssl-certificate, thin

So I just cloned a repo that I recently had running on my mac. It is using thin ssl to start the server but when I run the same command I would run a few months ago it throws an error.

Here is the command:

```
thin start --ssl --ssl-verify --ssl-key-file server.key --ssl-cert-file server.crt
```

And here is the error:

```
Users/lukeholloway/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p576/gems/thin-1.6.3/lib/thin/runner.rb:147:in `parse!': invalid option: --ssl-verify (OptionParser::InvalidOption)
from /Users/lukeholloway/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p576/gems/thin-1.6.3/lib/thin/runner.rb:50:in `initialize'
from /Users/lukeholloway/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p576/gems/thin-1.6.3/bin/thin:6:in `new'
from /Users/lukeholloway/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p576/gems/thin-1.6.3/bin/thin:6:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/lukeholloway/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p576/bin/thin:23:in `load'
from /Users/lukeholloway/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p576/bin/thin:23:in `<main>'
from /Users/lukeholloway/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p576/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
from /Users/lukeholloway/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p576/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

I tried using commonsense to read the error but it isn't giving me anything to go on. I have looked all over for answers and even made a new certificate following this tutorial: http://www.napcsweb.com/blog/2013/07/21/rails_ssl_simple_wa/. Still getting the same error whatever I do though. Though only thing that has changed on my computer since I last had it is that I upgraded to Yosemite since then(not sure if that makes a difference or not).

Here are the versions of everything:
- Ruby 2.0.0
- Rails 4.0.2
- Thin 1.6.3
- Mac OSX Yosemite

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, my own common sense says `invalid option: --ssl-verify` means that `--ssl-verify` is not a valid option for the version of thin you now are using.

I don't know if that means you are using an older or newer version of thin. But your stacktrace tells me you're using thin-1.6.3.  Which is the [latest released version of thin](https://rubygems.org/gems/thin).

Perhaps it no longer supports --ssl-verify? Checking the thing [CHANGELOG](https://github.com/macournoyer/thin/blob/master/CHANGELOG), at 1.6.2, we see "Remove `---ssl-verify` option as EventMachine doesn't verify the certificate".

So I'd say you are definitely using a different more recent version of thin than you were a couple months ago. And the recent version of thin is no longer capable of verifying ssl certs, which may or may not be a problem for you (not sure exactly where it was verifying them), but to use the latest version of thin, remove the "--ssl-verify" option from the command line: `invalid option: --ssl-verify`